# ¿Como hago para colocar texto de String cambio2[imx][imy] en el JButton boton[imx][imy]?

Tags: java-8

```
package ProgramasPersonales;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ResuelveSudoku {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Marco1 marco=new Marco1();

        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

}


class Marco1 extends JFrame{

    public Marco1(){

        setTitle("Sudoku");

        setResizable(false);

        setBounds(450,150,400,400);

        lamina1 lamina=new lamina1();

        add(lamina);

        setVisible(true);
    }

}

class lamina1 extends JPanel{

    public lamina1() {

        EventosRaton click=new EventosRaton();



        for(x=0;x<9;x++) {

            for(y=0;y<9;y++) {

                boton[x][y]=new JButton("0");
                add(boton[x][y]);
                Sudoku.add(boton[x][y]);
                boton[x][y].addMouseListener(click);
            }

        }

        ResuelveSudoku resuelve=new ResuelveSudoku();

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        BotonResolver=new JButton("Resolver");

        Sudoku.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,9));

        add(Sudoku,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(BotonResolver,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        BotonResolver.addActionListener(resuelve);

    }

    class EventosRaton extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener{

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            if(contador==0) {

                if(e.getModifiersEx()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) {

                    int xx=e.getXOnScreen();
                    int yy=e.getYOnScreen();

                    yy=yy-177;
                    xx=xx-456;

                    if(xx<=42) {
                        xx=0;
                    }else if(xx<=85) {
                        xx=1;
                    }else if(xx<=128) {
                        xx=2;
                    }else if(xx<=171) {
                        xx=3;
                    }else if(xx<=214) {
                        xx=4;
                    }else if(xx<=257) {
                        xx=5;
                    }else if(xx<300) {
                        xx=6;
                    }else if(xx<343) {
                        xx=7;
                    }else {
                        xx=8;
                    }

                    if(yy<=37) {
                        yy=0;
                    }else if(yy<=75) {
                        yy=1;
                    }else if(yy<=113) {
                        yy=2;
                    }else if(yy<=151) {
                        yy=3;
                    }else if(yy<=189) {
                        yy=4;
                    }else if(yy<=227) {
                        yy=5;
                    }else if(yy<265) {
                        yy=6;
                    }else if(yy<303) {
                        yy=7;
                    }else {
                        yy=8;
                    }

                    String entrada=boton[yy][xx].getText();

                    int cambio=Integer.parseInt(entrada);

                    if(cambio<=8) {
                        cambio++;
                    }else {
                        cambio=0;
                    }

                    boton[yy][xx].setText(""+cambio);

                }
            }


        }

    }

    private class ResuelveSudoku implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(contador==0) {

                for(int a=0;a<9;a++) {

                    for(int b=0;b<9;b++) {

                        boton[a][b].setEnabled(false);

                        numeral[a][b]=Integer.parseInt(boton[a][b].getText());

                        if(numeral[a][b]>0) {
                            constante[a][b]=numeral[a][b];
                        }else {
                            numeral[a][b]=1;
                            constante[a][b]=0;


                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            for(int cont=0;cont<9;cont++) {

                    for(int n=0;n<9;n++) {

                        if(n==cont) {

                            n++;
                            if(n>8) {
                                n=0;
                            }
                        }

                        if(numeral[0][cont]==numeral[0][n]) {

                            if(constante[0][cont]>0) {

                                n=9;

                            }else {

                                numeral[0][cont]++;
                                if(numeral[0][cont]==10) {
                                    numeral[0][cont]=1;
                                    n=0;
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

            }

            for(int imx=0;imx<9;imx++) {

                for(int imy=0;imy<9;imy++) {

                    cambio2[imx][imy]=""+numeral[imx][imy];

                    boton[imx][imy]=boton[imx][imy].setText(cambio2[imx][imy]);
                }
            }

            contador=1;


        }


    }

    String cambio2[][]=new String[9][9];
    int constante[][]=new int[9][9];
    int numeral[][]=new int[9][9];
    int x,y,contador=0,cont=0;
    JButton boton[][]=new JButton [9][9];
    private JPanel Sudoku=new JPanel();
    private JButton BotonResolver;

}
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

Comment: ¡ Stackoverflow en español !
Y no veo ninguna pregunta. Sólo el título.

Comment: esta linea del codigo "boton[imx][imy]=boton[imx][imy].setText(cambio2[imx][imy]);" me marca un error que dice "You cannot convert from void to Jbutton"

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema reside en la línea

```
boton[imx][imy]=boton[imx][imy].setText(cambio2[imx][imy]);
```

En esta línea lo que estás haciendo es igualar cada uno de los botones al resultado que devuelva la operación [setText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText(java.lang.String)) (que es void como te comentan por arriba, así que no devolverá nada). Al ser Java un lenguaje orientado a objetos, lo único que tendrías que hacer es simplemente eliminar la igualación y utilizar el método directamente:

```
boton[imx][imy].setText(cambio2[imx][imy]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!